# Which posts apper on Twitter "Replies" tab?

Tags: twitter

I'm new to Twitter and I use it in a web-browser on my phone.

When I open somebody's profile and go to "Replies" tab on their profile, I see the replies that this person gave to various tweets. It looks like this: an original tweet, and a reply below. There's also a grey vertical line on the left side, connecting the original tweet and the reply.
The reply contains a mark "Replying to...". This is pretty clear to me.

But some posts in this "Replies" tab are not connected to any other tweets, are not linked to them with a grey line, and do not start with a "Replying to..." mark. They look just like a simple tweet, not a reply. What are these tweets? Why are they shown in "Replies" tab?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please avoid the use of salutations and thanks. For details see [Expected behavior](https://webapps.stackexchange.com). I suggest you look at the [Twitter help center](https://help.twitter.com/en) and search this site thoroughly before asking a question. Include the most relevant findings and why they were not helpful to you. Ref. [ask]. [Guides to ask a question about a web application](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4946/88163).

Comment: Thank you Ruben. I've searched Twitter Help Center, Google, this website and what not. Maybe the users of this website know the answer)